# Why does the re.sub() function is return an empty string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
string = '(month)April(year)'
```

If I want to use re.sub to only end up with the month how would I do that?
So far I have been using

```
re.sub(r'(.+)', '', string)
```

but I end up with a completely empty string

Comment: all of them have the parentheses sets, but in some cases it has a different string besides month or year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis, otherwise they are considered part of the regex. Something like this does the trick:

```
string = '(month)April(year)'
re.sub(r'\(\w+\)', '', string)
# April
```

See it also on https://regex101.com/r/vOjpRU/1